# Environment variable not available in python

Tags: bash, python, environment-variables

I have a pretty interesting problem regarding environment variables, and googling around didn't show me any meaningful results:

```
$ echo $BUCKET && python -c "import os; print os.environ['BUCKET']"
mule-uploader-demo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'BUCKET'
```

So I have an environment variable that is available in bash but not inside python. How can this happen and how do I fix it? Here are some additional details:

- The environment variable is set through a `source envvars.sh` command
- The `envvars.sh` file contains only lines that look like this: `KEY=value`
- I've reproduced this in both bash and zsh
- If I do an `export BUCKET=$BUCKET`, it works

Comment: can you do `env | grep BUCKET`? if it's not exported it won't be available to child processes.

Comment: nope, it's not in there. But why? I can `echo $BUCKET`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the variable scope in bash. `export` makes your variable available to subprocesses, see for example:

```
→ export BUCKET=foo 
→ env | grep BUCKET
80:BUCKET=foo
→ PAIL=bar  
→ env | grep PAIL  # no output
→ python -c "import os; print os.environ['BUCKET']"
foo
→ python -c "import os; print os.environ['PAIL']"  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PAIL'
→ CAN=baz python -c "import os; print os.environ['CAN']"
baz
```

so in a child process `PAIL` is a fail.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that using `source [filename]` would export the variables automatically, but apparently this is not the case. Thanks!